# split a array of strings of words while maintaining the word column order

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string as

```
        WP(PIL)/7/2013        PUBLIC AND PANCHAYAT               MS PEMA BHUTIA            MR. S.K. CHETTRI,\n                                KABI LUNGCHUK                      MS PANILA THEENGH         ASST. GOVT.\n                                CONSTITUENCY, NORTH                MS MON MAYA SUBBA         ADVOCATE\n                                SIKKIM                             MS TASHI DOMA SHERPA      MR. KARMA THINLAY,\n                                Vs                                 MR SANGAY GURMEY          CENTRAL GOVT.\n                                THE SECRETARY, MINISTRY            BHUTIA                    COUNSEL\n                                OF SURFACE TRANSPORT               MR. JORGAY NAMKA          MR THINLAY DORJEE\n                                AND ORS.                           MR. ZANGPO SHERPA,        BHUTIA\n                                                                   AMICUS CURIAE             MS POLLIN RAI, ASST.\n                                                                                             GOVT. ADVOCATE\n
```

which I split using the '\n' char. It results in

```
["        WP(PIL)/7/2013        PUBLIC AND PANCHAYAT               MS PEMA BHUTIA            MR. S.K. CHETTRI,",
"                                KABI LUNGCHUK                      MS PANILA THEENGH         ASST. GOVT.",
"                                CONSTITUENCY, NORTH                MS MON MAYA SUBBA         ADVOCATE",
"                                SIKKIM                             MS TASHI DOMA SHERPA      MR. KARMA THINLAY,",
"                                Vs                                 MR SANGAY GURMEY          CENTRAL GOVT.",
"                                THE SECRETARY, MINISTRY            BHUTIA                    COUNSEL",
"                                OF SURFACE TRANSPORT               MR. JORGAY NAMKA          MR THINLAY DORJEE",
"                                AND ORS.                           MR. ZANGPO SHERPA,        BHUTIA",
"                                                                   AMICUS CURIAE             MS POLLIN RAI, ASST.",
"                                                                                             GOVT. ADVOCATE"]
```

I would like to extract the 4 columns for each row(ie convert array of strings to matrix). Also, the extracted string should belong to the associated column. eg 'GOVT. ADVOCATE' in the last string should belong extracted as ['', '', '', 'GOVT. ADVOCATE']

I am using **docsplit** library to parse pdf which has tabular data. The problem is that each row in the pdf has internal table which is similar to the array of strings that are specified below.

I tried getting the index of the first char of word for each column as a reference and use those values for processing the strings but haven't been able to have a working solution.

Comment: I'm a bit scared off when I see that only the first row has 4 actual columns, while all other rows only have 3.  Is this a typo, or is your data actually like this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its the actual data.

Comment: What are column delimiters? If you can define the pattern, you may use a regex. Else, you should do that manually.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we don't have any column delimiters. The presence of more than 1 space can be assumed to be. The only thing that we have is the string with newline chars. I broke the string on newline char and have this array. Only regex wont help cause the last row string has only 2 words which logically belong to the last column.

Comment: So, you asked a question that has no answer as you have no specifications.

Comment: That data is supposed to be read column-wise not row-wise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not completely true. the array is a collection of strings. the words in each string start at any index. We can assume that the words in the following strings will start at the same indices as the words in the first one.

Comment: Then post your code. Without it, the question is off-topic.

Comment: _"will start at the same indices"_ – they don't, your first row is off by 2 chars.

Comment: @prasad.surase where does the data come from?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am currently trying to use "a,b,c,d = arr.first.scan(/\s{2,}\S{2}/).map{|substr| arr.first.index(substr.strip) }"

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I assume your PDF is [20062017_3008_1001.pdf](http://highcourtofsikkim.nic.in/hcs/sites/default/files/Cause%20List/20062017_3008_1001.pdf)? If so, your PDF library did a lousy job. The PDF already contains columns. Try to select the text with Adobe Acrobat (or any other sane PDF tool) and you'll see that it gets selected column-wise (not row-wise).

Comment: BTW, your first column is probably off by 2 characters because you are missing the initial `3)`.

Comment: @Stefan agreed that it's an lousy job but its not generated by us. else, we wouldn't be parsing it. It should be programatically solvable.

Comment: @prasad.surase the PDF is fine, they did a good job. It's your parsing tool that is faulty. It doesn't handle the text flow correctly.

Comment: @stefan I get the first string after using docsplit. The problem is, thats all the data I have. I am trying to find a solution or pointers to the possible approaches that can get me a solution.

Comment: _"after using docsplit"_ – show your code, please. How to you invoke docsplit?

Comment: Parsing stuff like this into data structures has literally been my profession for most of the last 28 years.  Unfortunately, there is no generic answer; you will have to [a] make up a spec that fits the data, [b] write custom parser code to that spec, [c] pray to the god(s) that the data never violates your made-up spec in the future.

I am actually using my experience in this field to create a more generic tool, but it is extremely proprietary, and very expensive.  :)

Comment: Step 1: develop a "column analyzer" class that injests multiple lines and analyzes them for column left/right positions, and spits them out.  This would probably iteratively use `String#match` and `MatchData#offset` to find column starting/ending positions.  The patterns `\s\s\w` and `\w\s\s` would be useful for left/right column positions.  The analysis would adjust based on min (for left) and max(for right) before returning.  Step 2: use the column positions from the analysis and extract strings using `String#[]` and `String#strip!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution based on my comment above:

```
require 'pp'

test_array = ["        WP(PIL)/7/2013        PUBLIC AND PANCHAYAT               MS PEMA BHUTIA            MR. S.K. CHETTRI,",
"                                KABI LUNGCHUK                      MS PANILA THEENGH         ASST. GOVT.",
"                                CONSTITUENCY, NORTH                MS MON MAYA SUBBA         ADVOCATE",
"                                SIKKIM                             MS TASHI DOMA SHERPA      MR. KARMA THINLAY,",
"                                Vs                                 MR SANGAY GURMEY          CENTRAL GOVT.",
"                                THE SECRETARY, MINISTRY            BHUTIA                    COUNSEL",
"                                OF SURFACE TRANSPORT               MR. JORGAY NAMKA          MR THINLAY DORJEE",
"                                AND ORS.                           MR. ZANGPO SHERPA,        BHUTIA",
"                                                                   AMICUS CURIAE             MS POLLIN RAI, ASST.",
"                                                                                             GOVT. ADVOCATE"]

class ColumnAnalyzer

  attr_reader :columns
  attr_accessor :array

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
    analyze
  end

  def analyze
    lefts = Array.new
    rights = Array.new
    @array.each do |line|
      pos_left =  Array.new
      deconstruct = line.dup
      col = 0
      while m = deconstruct.match(/\s\s[^\s]{1}/) do
        left = m.offset(0)[0]+1
        pos_left[col] = col == 0 ? left : left + pos_left[col-1]
        col += 1
        deconstruct = deconstruct[left+1..-1]
      end
      lefts.push pos_left
      pos_right = Array.new
      deconstruct = line.dup
      col = 0
      while m = deconstruct.match(/[^\s]{1}\s\s/) do
        right = m.offset(0)[0]
        pos_right[col] = col == 0 ? right : right + pos_right[col-1]
        col += 1
        deconstruct = deconstruct[right+1..-1]
      end
      pos_right.push line.length
      rights.push pos_right
    end
    cols_l = lefts.collect { |a| a.size }.max 
    cols_r = rights.collect { |a| a.size }.max
    cols = [cols_l,cols_r].max # no. of columns
    @columns = Array.new
    (0..cols-1).each do |col|
      @columns[col] = Hash.new
      @columns[col][:l] = lefts.map { |a| a[col] }.min
      lefts.select { |a| a.size < cols }.map! { |a| a.unshift 0 }
      rights.select { |a| a.size < cols }.map! { |a| a.unshift 0 }
    end
    (0..cols-1).each do |col|
      @columns[col][:r]  = rights.map { |a| a[col] }.max
    end
  end

  def extract
    data = Array.new
    @array.each do |line|
      line_array = Array.new
      @columns.each do |col|
        line_array.push line[col[:l]..col[:r]].strip!
      end
      data.push line_array
    end
    data
  end

end

ca = ColumnAnalyzer.new(test_array)
data = ca.extract
pp ca.columns
pp data

=> [{:l=>7, :r=>21}, {:l=>28, :r=>54}, {:l=>62, :r=>85}, {:l=>87, :r=>113}]
[["WP(PIL)/7/2013",
  "PUBLIC AND PANCHAYAT",
  "MS PEMA BHUTIA",
  "MR. S.K. CHETTRI,"],
 ["", "KABI LUNGCHUK", "MS PANILA THEENGH", "ASST. GOVT."],
 ["", "CONSTITUENCY, NORTH", "MS MON MAYA SUBBA", "ADVOCATE"],
 ["", "SIKKIM", "MS TASHI DOMA SHERP", "MR. KARMA THINLAY,"],
 ["", "Vs", "MR SANGAY GURMEY", "CENTRAL GOVT."],
 ["", "THE SECRETARY, MINISTRY", "BHUTIA", "COUNSEL"],
 ["", "OF SURFACE TRANSPORT", "MR. JORGAY NAMKA", "MR THINLAY DORJEE"],
 ["", "AND ORS.", "MR. ZANGPO SHERPA,", "BHUTIA"],
 ["", "", "AMICUS CURIAE", "MS POLLIN RAI, ASST."],
 ["", "", "", "GOVT. ADVOCATE"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above problem. Its not a perfect solution but it works for most of the cases.

I have assumed that the first string in the array is the longest(has data for all columns).

Docsplit is irrelevant in the context of the current question. Anyways, add in Gemfile

```
gem 'docsplit', git: 'git@github.com:prasadsurase/docsplit.git', branch: 'layout-nopgbrk-support'
```

Run the below code in console to get the text from pdf.

```
Docsplit.extract_text(pdf_file_path, { layout: true, nopgbrk: true, output: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf_to_text/" })
```

Assuming that are only 4 logical columns of data

```
indices = arr.first.scan(/\s{2,}\S{2,3}\s{1}*/).map{|substr| arr.first.index(substr.strip) }
count = indices.count
actual_data = arr.map do |str|
  record = []
  count.times do |i|
    record << [count - 1  == i ? str[indices[i]..-1] : str[indices[i]..indices[i+1] - 1]]
  end
  record
end

details = [:first, :second, :third, :fourth].map do |indx|
  actual_data.map(&indx).join('').strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
end
```

**details** is an array of 4 strings.

Comment: You'll note that my solution above (which you accepted, thanks) does not depend on there being 4 columns, any number of columns will work.  There are other ways to make it fail, though, like there not being 2 spaces in front of the first column, or overlapping columns (the left of column 2 is left of the right of column 1).